# How to bind data in D3 using a function

Tags: data-binding, d3.js

I am having trouble determining how D3 calls my "bind data function."  I see my function called (with null and what appears like an index), but what are the arguments provided? How many times will D3 call this function? What are the obligations of `myDataFunction`?

```
circlesGroup.selectAll('circle').data( myDataFunction, myKeyFunction );
```

Comment: The first argument to `.data()` should be a data array or a function that returns a data array. It will be called once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Lars Kotthoff said in the comments, when you use the form `.data( dataFunction, keyFunction )`, your data function should return an array of data values.

But why use a function at all, and what are the parameters to it?  This structure is useful if you have nested selections.  Nested selections maintain a two-level hierarchy: each of the elements in the child selection is grouped according to their ancestor element in the parent selection.

When you do

```
parentSelection.selectAll(".childElements").data( dataFunction, keyFunction )
```

The data function will be called once for *each* element in `parentSelection`, and it must return an array of data to be used as for children of that parent element.

Your function will be passed the data and index of the parent object as parameters in the standard `function(d,i)` format.  Your function then uses the parent data and/or index to determine the child data array.  In the simplest situation, your parent data object *is* an array, and you just use `function(d){return d;}` to assign each element of the array to a different child.

Mike Bostock's [Nested Selections tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) gives examples of using nested selections to create a table.  Nested selections are also used to create "small multiple" graphs like [these donut charts](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3888852): The first selection defines each pie/donut, and then the nested selection uses a data function to generate the data array for each individual slice.

Comment: No problem.  It's an important, if confusing, concept.  By the way, if you *want* to have a data function called on each existing element to calculate the new data value, you can use [`selection.datum(datumFunction)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-datum).  In this case `datumFunction` will be called for *each* element in the selection, and passed the data already bound to that element plus its index.  It only works for existing elements, however: it doesn't create an `enter()` or `exit()` option.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data):

> The specified values is an array of data values, such as an array of numbers or objects, or a function that returns an array of values.

The first argument to `.data()` should be a data array or a function that returns a data array. It will be called once.

Comment: Not quite.  Or at least, an over-simplification; in this case, the data function might only be called once, but that's only because the `circlesGroup` selection only contains a single `<g>` element.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter how many elements the selection contains. `.data()` matches the data to those elements, i.e. both elements and data are compared. For this, it's not necessary to call the data function more than once (indeed it would result in duplicate elements). The only case where it may be called more than once is, as you point out, for nested selections.

Comment: It is technically a nested selection; `circlesGroup` is the parent selection, which I'm assuming only contains a single `<g>` and no bound data, so the function was being called once and passed null for the data parameter.